# JavaScript: How to make a promise that never resolves or rejects

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using:

```
 await Promise.race([promise1, promise2]);
```

The logic is if `promise1` has not resolved/rejected within 5s, then `promise2` might be able to resolve. So after a delay `promise2` tries to do its thing, if it fails I wish to have `promise2` return a `Promise` that never resolves so that its all up to waiting for `promise1`.

I tried

```
async function promise2(timeout=5000) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
    if (didStuffAndOK())  {
        return "OK"
    }
    return new Promise( () => {} )
}
```

`return new Promise( () => {} )` seems to be interpreted as the promise being rejected rather than never resolved.

How does one make an empty promise (not in real life, in JavaScript)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make `promise1` reject if timeout is reached and wrap it up with `try/catch` and fallback to `promise` when `catch` clause is invoked?

Comment: Well that behaviour is different, because if promise2  doesnt work, I wish to give promise1 its time to continue. promise1 is a fetch, then let it take longer if theres not cache hit from promise 2

Comment: *promise1 is a fetch, then let it take longer if theres not cache hit from promise 2* Is promise2 meant as a 'cache' for promise1 results ? In that case, chaining should solve it: start with promise2, if if fails proceed with promise1. Even better: make the caching transparent by moving it inside promise1 itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer straight your question `new Promise( () => {} )` never resolves.

Here is the prof :

```js
new Promise(()=>{})
   .then(()=> console.log('promise resolved'))
   .catch(()=>console.log('promise rejected'));
console.log('FOO, so that you can see that the code was executed');
```

But I guess you have a diffrent question.

```
The logic is if promise1 has not resolved/rejected within 5s, then promise2 
might be able to resolve. So after a delay promise2 tries to do its thing, if it 
fails I wish to have promise2 return a Promise that never resolves so that its 
all up to waiting for promise1.
```

For this you can resolve in the `promise2` the `promise1`, because promises are chainable.

```js
(async ()=>{

  const promise1 = new Promise(()=>{}) // simulating here a very long fetch;
  
  const promise2 = new Promise((res)=>{
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
        try {
          console.log('one second passed and the fetch is still running');
          throw Error() // simulating a promise2 does it thing and fails
        } catch (e){
          res(promise1); // Chain promise1 back
        }
     }, 1000);
   });  
   await Promise.race([promise1, promise2]);
   console.log('This won\'t be printed because the previous line awaits for promise1');
})()
```

Comment: Jeepers that is brilliant. I would never of thouse of that. Took me a while to figure it ouy. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, The answer here covered just what you have asked for, another addition would be to catch on the `race()` call in case the `promise1` fails before the timeout, in that scenario, as I layed it out the promise2 won't help.  
Also may be better to check the cache first and only after that to make a fetch, but that is up to your requirements.